# Trying to make Binary Search Tree, but program freezes. Can you check my code?

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

Is there something in this that I don't understand or is this one of those times that I'm going to need to use the ***alloc*** functions from ***stdlib.h*** that I have never used before.

```
struct node {
    int value;
    node* left; 
    node* right; 
    node* parent;
};
```

This is the code that makes the program crash.

```
    // Is the value > current node?
    // If it is, then go right,
    // If not then go left.
    // Is there a node forward?
    // If not then create a node with the value.
    node currentNode = rootNode;
    bool newNodeCreated = false;
    while (newNodeCreated == false){

        if (value > currentNode.value){                     // If the value is greater than the currents node. 
            if (currentNode.right != NULL){                     // Check the child on the right. 
                currentNode = *currentNode.right;                   // Set the current node to the child and restart the loop. 
            } else {                                                
                currentNode.right->value = value;                   // Set a new node.
                currentNode.right->parent = &currentNode;

                newNodeCreated = true;                      // End loop. 
            }
        } else {                                            // If the value is less than the current node. 
            if (currentNode.left != NULL){                      // Check the child on the left. 
                currentNode = *currentNode.left;                    // Set the current node to the child and restart the loop. 
            } else {                                                
                currentNode.left->value = value;                    // Set a new node. 
                currentNode.left->parent = &currentNode;

                newNodeCreated = true;                      // End loop. 
            }
        }
    }
    return;
```

Comment: It probably doesn't "freeze", it just goes into an infinite loop unless you get a specific crash outcome. Have you dropped it into a debugger to see where it gets stuck?

Comment: I have tried but it freezes anyway. I put the breakpoint at the top of the loop.

Comment: When you say "freezes" what do you mean? Code doesn't "freeze", computers do.

Comment: You used the word "crash" in your question, does it freeze or crash?

Comment: It strops working and goes behind my IDE window. No errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a node, the values inside are set to nonsense ("garbage values") until you explicitly set them. C doesn't do any initialization for you, so the values are whatever was in RAM before you ran your code.

So when you check if the left/right children are `NULL`, they may be `NULL` if the random value happens to be `0`, but they also may not and may just point to a random memory address that may or may not be in your program's address space. Regardless, another node doesn't actually exist there until you make one.

Allocating memory is pretty simple. To make a new node, all you have to do is

```
node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
if (!newNode) {
    // Your program has run out of memory!
    exit(1);
}
```

and when you want to remove that node, call `free` on its pointer.

```
free(newNode);
```

Once you've actually allocated memory, you can use that pointer to add the new node to the tree.

```
// ...
} else {  
    currentNode.right = newNode;                                            
    currentNode.right->value = value;
    currentNode.right->parent = currentNode;
    // Explicitly set right and left on the new node to null
    currentNode.right->right = NULL;
    currentNode.right->left = NULL;

    newNodeCreated = true;
}
// ...
```

You may want to change `currentNode` to a `node*` instead of a `node` to avoid copying nodes in memory, but that's unrelated to the answer here.

Comment: Wow, you make me feel so special Elan Hamburger :) What is the culture around who gets the right answer? You put in more effort but MLeblanc answered before you could refresh the page to see recent activity.

Comment: The checkmark is for the "best" answer. Whether the best answer is the fastest or most complete (or somewhere in between, or on totally different criteria) is up to you. You can always show your support for an answer (or question) you found "useful" by giving an upvote.

Comment: Ok you helped me even more by telling me to set the left and the right nodes to NULL. So I marked your answer as right because in the end it had more helpful details.

Answer (score 0):

if currentNode.right == NULL , then the first instruction executed is:

currentNode.right->value = value;

you must allocate currentNode.right first.

```
if (currentNode.right != NULL){                     // Check the child on the right. 
                currentNode = *currentNode.right;                   // Set the current node to the child and restart the loop. 
            } else {                                                
                currentNode.right->value = value;                   // Set a new node.
                currentNode.right->parent = &currentNode;
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this. It's just that I have never used the heap before, I was hoping that I wouldn't need to.

Comment: and same things goes for the left node, you have to allocate it first before settings its value

Comment: Thanks! I have no way of checking if it works yet but the program doesn't crash, so I think it works. I guess using the heap isn't so complex after all. Any idea why someone downvoted this question? @MLeblanc